# Customize table columns

Tags: usability, buttons, data-tables

What is the best practice to place customize columns button for the Data table.
Please suggest if am right with the images added.[image]

Comment: What property of the columns should be customized in this way?

Comment: @Lex only the column headers..adding new or removing exist  by simple checkbox selection

Answer (score 3):

[This responsive tables solution](http://gergeo.se/RWD-Table-Patterns/) is very similar to the implementation you're considering and it works fairly well:

[image: Responsive table]

Choosing which columns you should show by default and which are safe to “hide” is the biggest consideration. There's a danger when using this kind of pattern that you end up over complicating the interface due to too many options.

Comment: a slightly better alternative to this table is to have a simple dropdown at the top which has 2 buttons inside in the first row each taking 50% width, a search bar just below or above it where you can type column names followed by each column name with a checkbox in front of it

Answer (score 1):

There's no "right" in design.

To propose a good solution:

- Make sure you comply to 10 usability heuristics by Nielsen.
- Make sure technical limitations won't change the final UI dramatically.
- Test the design with users. Let them complete a real task and see whether they can easily finish it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the options:
[image] 
It depends on design goals, but customizing the headers looks like secondary action for advanced users. Then you need no to make the control too prominent.

And follow @digsrafik's recommendations, these are general, but you didn't specify the goals and context in your question.